# How can I run the same tests for multiple data structures with pytest?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest

I have a module with various implementations of the same abstract base class. As an example, let's say I would want to test classes with the base class `collections.abc.Collection` which all have `append(element)` and `__contains__`. I want something like this:

```
import collections
collection_classes = [list, collections.deque]

@pytest.parameter_values(collection_classes)  # what I'm looking for
def test_contains(CollectionClass):
    collection = CollectionClass()
    words = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    for word in words:
        collection.append(word)
    for word in words:
        assert word in collection
```

Then I would want pytest to exectue the test with all given values **and** show an understandable error message if one (or more) of the parameters fails. Essentially as if I would have an own test for the parameter, just without the test code duplication.

### What I'm doing now

I have 3 classes which implement the same interface. As a work-around, I copied the test code into 3 different files which look almost identical, except for the import in the very top:

```
# speicific_collection is different for the 3 classes
from foo.module import specific_collection as CollectionClass
```

As I'm the only developer and as I'm not adding tests for this often, this is not a big deal. I still would like to know how to avoid this code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `pytest.mark.parametrize` with your classes:

```python
import pytest

collection_classes = (
    class1,
    class2
)

@pytest.mark.parametrize('cls', collection_classes)
def test_contains(cls):
    collection = cls()
    words = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    for word in words:
        collection.append(word)
    for word in words:
        assert word in collection
```